# Integrating CodeSniffer with Komodo IDE to sniff remote files

Tags: php, komodo, phpcodesniffer, komodoedit

I have CodeSniffer integrated with Komodo and I'm trying to CodeSniff remote (SCP) files. My issue is that CS tries to open the file instead of reading what's in memory in the editor pane. It can't open the SCP URL and fails. Has anybody been successful in getting CodeSniffer to look at the "local" version of a remote file?

Comment: PHP_CodeSniffer does accept standard input and is able to check it just fine. You can also tell it what the file path is in case your standards to things like check filenames and locations. But I have no experience doing this in Komodo. This Sublime plugin does it though: https://github.com/squizlabs/sublime-PHP_CodeSniffer , including the special first line to tell PHPCS the file path: https://github.com/squizlabs/sublime-PHP_CodeSniffer/blob/master/PHP_CodeSniffer.py#L195 . May not help with Komodo, but it's the only place I've seen STDIN used instead of a local file path.

Comment: Good to know. I'll take a look and see if I can get Komodo to pipe STDIN.